# Rank on SQLite SubQuery

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net

I have a table Person with ID(Guid), FirstName(string), LastName(string) and 3000 entries. What I desperately need is the rank of a certain entry by ID in a sorted query by FirstName and LastName.

So for example: I search for any entries with FirstName or LastName containing the String 'mil' which returns 62 entries sorted. Since I know the ID of an entry somewhere in this result, I need the row_index of this entry.

I tried this with a Temp Table before, but since I'm working with sqlite-pcl for UWP I can't use 'CREATE TEMP TABLE' statements and so on, thus I need a solution in a single query.

```
PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempQuery;
CREATE TEMP TABLE TempQuery AS SELECT ID FROM Person WHERE (Firstname LIKE '%mil%' OR LastName LIKE '%%');
SELECT rowid FROM TempQuery WHERE ID = '48a0231a-af41-450d-a291-5912d39119c9' LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "row_index"? The `rowid` column, or the position of a particular row in the list of results? If the latter, can you use the brand new 3.25.1 release?

Comment: I don't know "sqlite-pcl for UWP". If you cannot use `CREATE TEMP TABLE` statements, can you use `WITH {table_name} as`? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: Sorted by what? Your code doesn't sort at all, so the order is undefined.